# Conserve variable after refresh php

Tags: php, page-refresh

I have a PHP script that read and export CSV to a database. At the beginning of each execution, the script get a customer name with `$_POST`. It runs around 7 minutes to send 120k row. Nevertheless, my host allow PHP scripts to run up to 165 seconds.

My idea was then to refresh the page before the 165s and start the export again, at the row it ended. I've succedeed to refresh the page, but I struggle to conserve the variable saving the row position at which the script ended in order to use it after the refresh.
I could use `$_POST` or `$_SESSION`, but my script may run several time at the same moment, exporting a different CSV each run. I'm afraid that changing these super global variable from scripts that may run at the same time make them collide, and change their value when I don't want to.
First : is the above affirmation true?

Then if it is, how can I store the number of row the script ended before refreshing the page. I though about creating a file, putting the informations inside and then read it. That may look like this :

```
customer_name : Jon
row_ended : 10584

customer_name : Jane
row_ended : 11564
```

But isn't there a more easier and efficient solution?

Comment: Create a real session ID for each job and pass it thru. So you can ensure, you are working with the correct dataset.

Comment: The root of the problem appears to be that you have a *web page* that takes several minutes to execute.  Ideally a long-running process like this would be performed outside the context of the web application, such as a scheduled cron job.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a run ID and save it on the session.
Ex.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['run']['id'] = 1; // or some unique ID
$_SESSION['run']['user'] = 'jon';
$_SESSION['run']['lastRow']= 0;

$startTime = time() + 160; // total secs
if($starTime > time() ){
   // time of 160 passed redirect to same page.
   $_SESSION['run']['lastRow']= 100000;
   header("location: page.php");
   exit;
}
```

But this will not solve the problem, can be be a redirect hell

You can try to increase the max execution time at runtime.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0); //will run forever
```

or the best solution run it as a shell command with max_execition_time = 0
users may navigate away the page if it takes too long.